# Scroll to affix default position when links in container clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a tabbed contents using Jquery UI, and I got to make the tab selectors in fixed position using **[Bootstrap Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)**. Similar to the way Yahoo uses, for each tab selector link clicked, it triggers the scroll page to selectors default position in order to show tab content from the start.

Code snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/rpgrhhnt/1/

```
<div class="news-tickers scrollspy" id="scrollToHere">

<ul class="catselector affix-top" data-spy="affix">
    <li><a id="foo" href="#cat1">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="foo" href="#cat2">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="foo" href="#cat3">Category 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="cat1">cat1 content</div>
<div id="cat2">cat2 content</div>
<div id="cat3">cat3 content</div>

</div>
```

Using JQuery scrollTop, I managed to get the process for the first selector link (Category 1) to work when other tab selectors are active. Other selector links don't scroll to start when clicked!

```
$('#foo').click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollToHere").offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all - html elements should have unique ids. I've replaced `href` with expando attribute `data-pos` which have a jQuery selector for scroll-to-element. So `<a id="foo" href="#cat1">Category 1</a>` look like `<a class="foo" data-pos="#cat1">Category 1</a>` for now, and transform part of your JS to:

```
$('.foo').click(function () {
    var posElement = $($(this).data("pos"));
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: posElement.offset().top
    }, 800);
});
```

You can check out the result of these manipulations in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpgrhhnt/2/)

**Update** with affix and scrollspy: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpgrhhnt/6/)

**Update** with tabs with scroll effect: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpgrhhnt/7/)

Comment: You might did miss that your solution made JQuery UI tabs not working. Mostly caused for replacing href with data-pos.

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim I've just updated my answer. It has a simplified CSS of yours, so you can extend it as you wish. Affix and scrollspy are working too.

Comment: Just checked. All you have been doing is standard scrollspy, which is nothing new since already bootstrap have it.

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim Bootstrap's scrollspy requires `.nav` element.  So I've implemented own. BTW, is this variant corresponds your needs?

Comment: Using scrollspy while disable the TAB mainly is not a solution. I could do scrollspy easily if I had no TABS. http://jsfiddle.net/rpgrhhnt/1/